# The more interesting the question, the darker it should be

Tags: feature-request, tags, interesting-page

I like to identify interesting questions, based on my list of favorited tags.
But as I've got something like 40~ tags in this list, the light colorization in the questions list started to be ineffective: almost everything is colorized.

So I decided to run a self-made user-script to distinguish questions with a single interesting tag, from others with multiple ones:

```
var favorited = []; 
$('#interestingTags .post-tag').each(function() { 
    favorited.push($(this).html()); 
}); 
$('.question-summary').each(function() { 
    var n = 0; 
    $(this).find('.post-tag').each(function() { 
        if(favorited.indexOf($(this).html()) != -1) { 
            n++; 
        } 
    }); 
    $(this).css('background', 'rgba(255, 150, 0, 0.'+(n*2)+')'); 
});
```

And so my "Interesting" page looks like this:

[image]

What are your thoughts? Does this "feature" looks helpful to anybody else?
If yes, could it be feasible to make it native on SO?

Comment: If they go with different colors for interestingness, then they have to ditch the background color for some sort of icon because no one wants to stare at a page with a color at a bunch of different saturation levels all over the place.

Comment: @animuson It could effectively be more subtle. Something like a colorized border for example.

Comment: I'd like to see this implemented in some form. Maybe a colored border or colored edge instead of the background color.

Comment: Why not go in the opposite direction to get the less interesting questions more views? They're the ones that are having trouble attracting answers.

Comment: @KevinB This should not be the behavior of the "Interesting" tab. When I want to dive into the deep questions' sea, I use the "Newest", or "Active" tab.

Comment: "We've discovered this really odd behavior when fooing bars recursively with three processor cores disabled (they are disabled to save power). My coworker managed to put together the following MCVE before the dogs got him. If we can fix this segfault we'll be able to remotely force a system reboot, and that should get the power back on. Hopefully someone answers before the generator runs out of diesel. We would like to get the doors open if possible; Kelly has convinced most of us that hypothermia is preferable to starvation. Thanks in advance!"

Comment: Could we have the full script for this?

Comment: How are questions ordered on that tab? Can't they just be ordered by "interestingness"?

Comment: For me, there is too much going on in that picture...too many different colors.

Comment: I want a green bike shed.

Comment: Just tried this, and I have to say I like it a lot.

Comment: ...I only recently added my *second* favorite tag... I've started questioning myself which one of us is using the favorite tags in the wrong way.

Comment: @bakuru I use favorited tags to identify every question I'm supposed to be able to answer.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

What about something like this.

[image: Interesting question badges Screenshot]

Though it kind of looks like clutter, so maybe something closer to

[image: thin bars]

And KevinB's comment to OP:

> Why not go in the opposite direction to get the less interesting
>   questions more views? They're the ones that are having trouble
>   attracting answers.

It should probably change based on favorite tags, like the current yellow highlight system. Not on how popular the question is.

---

I like @MikeM's idea to just highlight the tags. Something like: [question-view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcjCd.png) and [hot-view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfF9G.png).

Here's some code to play with (run it in the console):

```js
// Gives all favorite tags the specified CSS
var favoritesCSS = function(css){
    var favs = $("#interestingTags").text().trim().split(" ");
    $(".tags > *").each(function(i,tag){
        var text = tag.innerText || tag.textContent;
        if(favs.indexOf(text) !== -1){
            $(tag).css(css);
        }
    });
};
// Usage
favoritesCSS({
    "font-weight":"normal",
    "background":"rgba(246, 138, 31, .3)"
});
```

Comment: I like the smaller icon you suggest, rather than the one in the image, but overall I like this better than background colours idea OP suggested. It seems bad design and headache-inducing to have the various shades on the page.

Comment: What about just highlighting the tags themselves? The favorites, I mean. No extra clutter needed.

Comment: Seeing good ideas changing into great ideas satisfies me.

Comment: @MikeM. good idea

Answer (score 5):

I [created a similar script](https://stackapps.com/questions/4762/tag-highlighting-on-main-so-page) as I was annoyed by the sea of yellow on the home page.

[image: Example]

Not sure how well it will scale to 40 tags but you can certainly amend the script linked.

Comment: Yours looks too much like an error log for my taste, but I think the possibility of adding one's own script is in general a good idea.
Maybe stack overflow could support this in the user settings

Comment: @memoryofadream You're welcome to change the colours! :)

Comment: Yeah, looks like "a friends" build radiator :-)

Comment: SO questions kind of _are_ an error log.

Comment: looks like Wireshark coloring theme `:)`

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you've solved *your* problem, you built a user script *perfect for you*.

Personally, I like the muted style uncluttered style and I want a site focused on questions, not arbitrary metrics about them.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I am a sucker for userscript ideas. I also only see color in my list of interesting questions. But I am not a huge fan of the color coding ideas presented (varying colors, error console, borders, etc).

Perhaps the questions could simply be ordered by the number of tags present which match your set of interesting tags.

```
var favorited = []; 
$('#interestingTags .post-tag').each(function() { 
 favorited.push($(this).html()); 
});
$('.question-summary').sort(function(a,b){
 var an = $('.post-tag',a).filter(function(){ 
            return favorited.indexOf($(this).html()) != -1 
          }).length,
     bn = $('.post-tag',b).filter(function(){ 
            return favorited.indexOf($(this).html()) != -1 }).length;
 if( an == bn ) return 0;
 return an < bn ? 1 : -1;
}).detach().appendTo('#question-mini-list');
```

Which would be in contrast to the amount of time past per last activity per post. It was at this point I began to consider whether or not the *amount* of favorite tags per post was really what dictated the level of interest.

I am not sure that the number of matched tags really correlates linearly with interest. Sometimes a single tag will hold far more weight of interest than another, or even than a set of them. All in all, while it was interesting to work with identifying "more interesting" questions based on their favorite tag count, I am not sold on the correlation and would believe status quo is probably good enough.

Alternatively, if you were really into color themes :)

[image]

<sub>user script not included because reasons</sub>

Comment: Yeah, you have a good point. Favorite tags per question isn't actually the best metric.